# Making a moving border animation work on a square element

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to get a moving border CSS animation to work on a square but I can't quite work out how to get it to work. It works fine on a circle as I just use the rotate transition with the key frames. This is my current markup.

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.box .border {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: border;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes border {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The animation in question is using a `rotate` transform with a *stationary* border to create the illusion of a moving border whereas it actually is not. With a square, you cannot use a similar model as when we rotate a square it doesn't stay the same like a circle does.

So the available options would be to make use of a SVG `stroke-dashoffset` based animation like in the below snippet. The `stroke-dasharray` property provides the length/width of the stroke (1<sup>st</sup> param) and the length/width of the space (2<sup>nd</sup> param). The `stroke-dashoffset` property specifies the offset from the start position at which the stroke should be painted.

```css
polygon {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 50, 750;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: none;
  animation: border 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes border {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -800;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="210" height="210">
  <polygon points="5,5 205,5 205,205 5,205" />
</svg>
```

---

If you want a **pure CSS solution** then you could make use of a ***linear-gradient*** based solution like in the below snippet. Here we create ***four strips*** of background images based on linear gradients which are of the same thickness of the border. These strips have the color for the required width and is then transparent for the rest. By animating the `background-position` , we can get something ***that is close*** to the effect that we are looking for.

Note that `background-position` animation works only with ***fixed pixel values*** and so the dimensions of the box need be known prior. Everytime the value changes, the `background-position` values need to be re-configured accordingly.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to right, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50px, transparent 50px);
  background-size: 100% 3px, 3px 100%, 100% 3px, 3px 100%; /* one of the values is the border thickness, other is 100% */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -50px 0px, right -50px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px; /* positions such that none of the images are visible at start */
  animation: border 5s linear; /* add infinite if you need infinite animation */
}
@keyframes border {
  /* animate position such that they come into view and go out of it one by one */
  25% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right -50px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='border-animation'></div>
```

If you want a pure CSS solution more closer to the SVG one then we can add more keyframes to the animation like the below snippet.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to right, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50px, transparent 50px);
  background-size: 100% 3px, 3px 100%, 100% 3px, 3px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -50px 0px, right -50px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  animation: border 5s linear;
}
@keyframes border {
  20% {
    background-position: 150px 0px, right -50px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 0px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  45% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 150px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, 150px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  70% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, 0px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px 150px;
  }
  95% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='border-animation'></div>
```

Here is an even more complete looking *infinite* animation using pure CSS:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to right, red 50px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50px, transparent 50px);
  background-size: 100% 3px, 3px 100%, 100% 3px, 3px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 0px, right -50px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  animation: border 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes border {
  20% {
    background-position: 150px 0px, right -50px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 0px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  45% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 150px, 200px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, 150px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  70% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, 0px bottom, 0px 200px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px 150px;
  }
  95% {
    background-position: 200px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px 0px;
  }
  95.1% {
    background-position: -50px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, right 200px, -50px bottom, 0px -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='border-animation'></div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic thanks so much for the in-depth reply! I wasn't aware of SVG based animation but it looks great. Will have a play with both this and the css version. Like you mentioned the round border was easy due to the rotation working round a circle that doesn't change so was just a little hack really to kind of get what I was looking for. Thanks again though much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You can pure css3 animated border to accomplish your task by just adding animated-border.min.css file. here is the code snippet.

```
<a href="ui-box top-leftStart">
  <span class='ui-border-element'>
    Animated Hyperlink
  </span>
</a>
```

Include this css file : https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/code-fx/Pure-CSS3-Animated-Border@V1.0/css/animated-border/animated-border.min.css

Demo link : https://code-fx.github.io/Pure-CSS3-Animated-Border/

I have created this demo page.

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site. If you do so, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose that it's your own site, it's often considered spam.  See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). While the domain for your demo makes it fairly clear you created it, Stack Overflow does require the disclosure to be explicit (e.g. "Demo link I created", would be sufficient).

Comment: You need to put the disclosure before the link, not elsewhere in the post. Make sure that, as I'm reading through, I'm already aware that it's your site before I've even seen the URL.